# Microsoft B2C to access microsoft graph api

Tags: spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I have a b2c angular application as client and a Spring boot backend as resource server. When my resource server receives an access token from the angular application, I want to make a call to the microsoft graph api after that to be able to find the user's. How can my resource server contact microsoft graph with access token from b2c endpoint?

Right now we have a functioning b2c client and resource server. But we don't know how to proceed to be able to contact microsoft graph api we our resource server in this case Spring boot